# Correct initializion with arguments

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Apologies for the dumb question, but I’m a beginner to Ruby.

I’m trying figure out how to pass arguments correctly to this gem from the constructor: https://github.com/miketierney/artii/blob/master/lib/artii/base.rb

I’m initializing an instance with `artii = Artii::Base.new([])` but I’d like to pass a different font name as an argument.

I’ve tried  `artii = Artii::Base.new([:font_name => ’slant'])` , as well as setting `artii.font_name` after initializing, but this doesn’t seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Many thanks,

Stephan

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
artii = Artii::Base.new({:font_name => ’slant'})
```